# eliminar pequeño espacio a la izquierda de lista no ordenada de menu

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente menú de perfil de usuario, con opciones básicas:

```
<ul class="profile-menu">
                    <li> <a class="profile-menu-trigger" data-trigger="dropdown" href="#">Logged in as Juanchi</a>
                        <ul class="profile-submenu submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

y su css que pongo también para darle forma

```
/* This is to locate the user menu */
.profile-menu{
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    
    }
    /* This is to create a submenu a give it shape */
    .profile-submenu{
        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        background: #fff ;
        margin-top: 30px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      
    }
    .submenu {
        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        background: #fff ;
        margin-top: 30px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
       display: none;
       
       
    }
    .submenu a {   /* This is to give shape to options inside menu affecting a's instead of <li> cause it is eassier */
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        display:block;
        color: #333;
        text-shadow: none;
        font-weight: 600;
        
    }
```

La cuestión es que cuando visualizo el menú, por alguna razón que desconozco, la primera letra de cada elemento `<a>` se encuentra desplazada ligeramente a la derecha sin embargo en ningún momento he usado `margin left`, ni `letter-spacing` ni nada que lo desplace. Adjunto foto.
[image: Espacio indeseado en menu de perfil de usuario.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso sucede porque las listas tienen por defecto un margen interno (padding).

Para quitarlo, simplemente agrega una regla para eliminarlo:

```
.profile-submenu{
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #fff ;
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    padding-left:0;
}
```